# How to select all columns but cast some into a different datatype in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to select all columns in postgres table but cast two columns into a different datatype but this creates duplicate columns

```
SELECT
  *, CAST(column1 AS varchar),
CAST(column2 AS varchar)
FROM
  my_table
```

I've tried to use Except to avoid duplicated columns but postgres has an issue with Except

```
SELECT
  * EXCEPT(column1, column2),
CAST(column1 AS varchar),
CAST(column2 AS varchar)
FROM
  my_table
```

What I'm I missing?

Comment: You can't make this work.  Either you will need to program some kind of script, or else you will have to list out all columns rather than using `SELECT *`.

Comment: Postgres does not have an issue with [EXCEPT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-select.html#SQL-EXCEPT) you just have not read the documentation and are using it incorrectly.

Comment: Just list explicitly all the column names you need  instead of using *.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes, looks at least like a good code golf task. But at the same time, I can see a real-world use for this (you want to save yourself a burden of upkeeping a lot of code when some columns may be dropped from a table, but not the ones you specifically care to cast in this query)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving column alias as below. You will get both the columns - actual as well as casted to varchar but with different names.

```
SELECT *,
       CAST(column1 AS varchar) as new_column1,
       CAST(column2 AS varchar) as new_column2
FROM
  my_table
```

Comment: This returns the columns column1 and column2 also, which is exactly what the requirement does not want.